# Scrapy crawler not able to crawl data

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

This code didn't collect data from pages, and I don't know why.

In VSCode, I get `SyntaxError: 'yield' outside function`, but in Jupyter notebook there's no error.

```
import scrapy

class multiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name='multiple'
        start_url = [
            'https://forum.moshaver.co/f232/',
            'https://forum.moshaver.co/f233/',
            'https://forum.moshaver.co/f241/',
            'https://forum.moshaver.co/f231/',
        ]       
def parse(self, response):
    for data in response.css('h3.threadtitle'):
        yield {
               'title': data.css('h3.threadtitle :: text').get(),
               'answers' : data.css('threadstats td alt :: text').get(),
               'writer' : data.css ('a.username offline popupctrl :: text').get(),
               'date_time' : data.css('span.label a::text').get(),
           } 
        next_page = response.css('span.selected pageitem a::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page:
            next_page = response.urljoin('next_page')
            yield scrapy.Request (url= next_page, callback = self.parse)
```

Comment: Please share a complete [MRE]: code that can be copied, pasted, and run as-is to reproduce the error described, as well as the full stack trace.

Comment: Add debugging details, and fix your indentations.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistakes are:

1. `start_url` should be `start_urls`.
2. In the CSS selectors you should remove the spaces around the `::`, e.g.: `'title': data.css('h3.threadtitle :: text').get()` -> `'title': data.css('h3.threadtitle::text').get()`. (this is where the error comes from, and BTW you shouldn't use scrapy in jupyter).
3. Your CSS selector for the next page is wrong.
4. You use `urljoin` wrong. You're using `next_page` as string instead of a variable.
5. The selectors for what you're trying to scrape are also wrong.

I fixed everything except number 5 as it's not relevant for the solution.

```py
import scrapy


class multiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'multiple'
    start_urls = [
        'https://forum.moshaver.co/f232/',
        'https://forum.moshaver.co/f233/',
        'https://forum.moshaver.co/f241/',
        'https://forum.moshaver.co/f231/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for data in response.css('h3.threadtitle'):
            yield {
                'title': data.css('h3.threadtitle::text').get(),
                'answers': data.css('threadstats td alt::text').get(),
                'writer': data.css ('a.username offline popupctrl::text').get(),
                'date_time': data.css('span.label a::text').get(),
            }
            next_page = response.css('span.prev_next a[rel="next"]::attr(href)').get()
            if next_page:
                next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
                yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page)     # parse is the default callback
```

Answer (score -1):

they only issue I see is that the closing bracket in this object is 3 spaces indented instead of 4 spaces, which may be the reason why you have the problem in vscode but you don't have it in jupyter

```
 yield {
           'title': data.css('h3.threadtitle :: text').get(),
           'answers' : data.css('threadstats td alt :: text').get(),
           'writer' : data.css ('a.username offline popupctrl :: text').get(),
           'date_time' : data.css('span.label a::text').get(),
    } 
 next_page = response.css('span.selected pageitem a::attr(href)').get()
```

If you are looking for more accurate advice please share the complete error message.
Furthermore, it seems that you have two separate problems:

1. your code has a syntax problem which you see when you use vscode (note: vscode is just the editor, the actual python interpreter is when you see in the command line when you run your script)
2. your code doesn't scrap anything or doesn't even start -> this is more likely a problem in the code itself, which is hard to say without seeing the actual page you are scrapping